# Fatal error: Call to a member function on non-object

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, magento-1.6

I am developing a custom module where an xml file will be created after order completion for each order.

I have called a function exportOrder on occuring of an event "sales_order_place_after". Following is the code of my function

```
public function exportOrder($observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    Mage::getModel('meteorify_observerexample/export')->exportOrder($order);
    return true;
}
```

Now In Export.php file i have written the logic of creation of an xml file.Export.php file is placed in the folder Meteorify/Observerexample/Model/ folder.

Here i have called the function exportOrder from the file Export.php using `Mage::getModel('meteorify_observerexample/export')->exportOrder($order);` but i am getting the error

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function exportOrder() on a non-object
>   in
>   /home/user_www/aliasgar/magentotesting/app/code/local/Meteorify/Observerexample/Model/Observer.php
>   on line 6"

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: How does the `config.xml` file of your module look like? I have a hung the helpers alias is not set properly.

Comment: This is how my helper config looks "<helpers>
        <orderexport>
            <class>Meteorify_Observerexample_Helper</class>
        </orderexport>
    </helpers>"

Comment: Models and events looks like this "<models>
        <meteorify_observerexample>
             <class>Observerexample_Model</class>
        </meteorify_observerexample>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <observers>
          <sales_order_place_after>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Meteorify_Observerexample_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>exportOrder</method>
          </sales_order_place_after>
        </observers>
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>     
    </events>"

Comment: Please add the contents of `config.xml` to the question. It's easier to read and follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `config.xml` file in the declaration of the model alias.
In your case is:

```
<models>
    <meteorify_observerexample>
        <class>Observerexample_Model</class>
    </meteorify_observerexample>
</models>
```

But it should be

```
<models>
    <meteorify_observerexample>
        <class>Meteorify_Observerexample_Model</class>
    </meteorify_observerexample>
</models>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it was a stupid mistake by me. As i am a newbie in magento, I repeatedly tend to make such mistakes. Now please can you guide me through this mistake too. In the file Export.php I have wrote the code for creating the order xml. Now i read from one of the article regarding fetching the orderdata using observer object. I am writing the code in the next comment

Comment: Following is the code i have wrote "public function exportOrder($order){
  $dirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('var').DS.'export';
 
  //if the export directory does not exist, create it
  if (!is_dir($dirPath)) {
    mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
  }
 
     $data = $order->getData();" Here i am getting the error 'Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /home/user_www/aliasgar/magentotesting/app/code/local/Meteorify/Observerexample/Model/Export.php on line 12' which is the line of code '$data = $order->getData()'

Comment: @Dexter. That is a different issue. Please post an other question with your code and your problem. Don't mix them.